# In Oracle how do I save a sequence.nextval in a variable to be reused in multiple inserts?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I'm writing a script to populate some tables with data for testing.

I would like to write something like the following but I don't know how to do it (I'm Oracle 11g)

```
SET ENABLED_USER_ID = SEQ.NEXTVAL; // PSEUDOCODE
SET DISABLED_USER_ID = SEQ.NEXTVAL; // PSEUDOCODE

INSERT INTO USERS
        (ID,      USR_NAME)
VALUES  (:ENABLED_USER_ID, 'ANDREW');
INSERT INTO CAR
       (CAR_ID,         CAR_NAME, USR_ID)
VALUES (CARSEQ.NEXTVAL, 'FORD',   :ENABLED_USER_ID);

INSERT INTO USERS
        (ID,      USR_NAME)
VALUES  (:DISABLED_USER_ID, 'ANDREW');
INSERT INTO CAR
       (CAR_ID,         CAR_NAME, USR_ID)
VALUES (CARSEQ.NEXTVAL, 'FORD',   :DISABLED_USER_ID);
```

I know I could rearrange the queries and use the `sequence.currval` reference, but I'd prefer to have the id saved in properly named variables.

Maybe I should just wrap the script in a `DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END;` but I'm hoping there is a more concise way to do it.

---

### Addition 27 May 2011 15:31

It seems that in any case I have to declare the variables in a `DECLARE` block. So I'm trying with

```
DECLARE
  USER_ID NUMBER(10,0) := 1;
BEGIN   
  insert into TEST_USER
  values (user_id, 'andrew', sysdate);   
END;
```

but I get the following error

> ```
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: **line 2, column 27:**
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
>   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
>   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
>   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
> ```

That points to the variable declaration.

I'm using java to load the script from a file and running it using the Oracle JDBC driver (ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar) on a Oracle 11g server.

The table TEST_USER has been created with

```
create table TEST_USERS (
    id number(10, 0) not null,
    name varchar2(100),
    date_ins date default sysdate,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it goes like this

```
DECLARE
    ENABLED_USER_ID PLS_INTEGER;
    DISABLED_USER_ID PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    ENABLED_USER_ID := SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    DISABLED_USER_ID := SEQ.NEXTVAL;

    INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USR_NAME)
    VALUES  (ENABLED_USER_ID, 'ANDREW');

    INSERT INTO CAR (CAR_ID, CAR_NAME, USR_ID)
    VALUES (CARSEQ.NEXTVAL, 'FORD', ENABLED_USER_ID);

    INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USR_NAME)
    VALUES  (DISABLED_USER_ID, 'ANDREW');

    INSERT INTO CAR (CAR_ID, CAR_NAME, USR_ID)
    VALUES (CARSEQ.NEXTVAL, 'FORD', DISABLED_USER_ID);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 10):

You would do this with the [RETURNING](http://psoug.org/snippet/INSERT-With-Returning-Clause_595.htm) clause in your first `INSERT` statement.

UPDATE: Happened to write about this in [my blog](http://gaiustech.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/ociml-support-for-returning/) recently.

Answer (score 8):

You will need a block if you are declaring variables

With 11g, [support for sequences has been improved](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/2268/new-plsql-feature-in-oracle-11g-the-use-of-sequencenextval) so you can use them like:

```
ENABLED_USER_ID := SEQ.NEXTVAL;
```

rather than using a `select` statement (though both will work)

Other options for persisting the values include saving them to a table or [creating a context](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/context.html), but I think `sequence.currval` is really the 'right answer' here

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT seq.nextval 
   INTO ENABLED_USER_ID
FROM dual;
```

Comment: ENABLED_USER_ID should go in a declare block right?

Comment: @Xan: yes, variables can only be defined in a DECLARE section which in turn is only valid if you have a PL/SQL block

Answer (score 4):

I think you can actually get away without any extra variables by using `currval`:

```
INSERT INTO USERS
    (ID,      USR_NAME)
VALUES  (SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'ANDREW');
INSERT INTO CAR
   (CAR_ID,         CAR_NAME, USR_ID)
VALUES (CARSEQ.NEXTVAL, 'FORD',   SEQ.CURRVAL);
```